# Speaking in first person without saying "I"

Tags: pronouns, ellipsis, deixis

For example:

> 今日から明日まで勉強します。
>   *kyou kara ashita made benkyou shimasu.*

How do I know that the speaker talks about themselves?

Comment: Context. So much of Japanese relies on context. You'll get used to it before long.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the context.

> ようこそ、アレフの講習会へ。今回の講習では今日から明日まで勉強します。明後日は発表があります。

In this context, the subject is "you."

> 日本太郎は、ノーベル物理学賞の最有力候補です。勉強などめったにしませんが、今日から明日まで勉強します。「勉強しているところを撮影させて欲しい」とのテレビ番組の取材をどうしても断れなかったからです。

Sorry for the weird example sentence, but in this context, the subject is 日本太郎.

> 今日から明日まで勉強します。

Without any other context, the subject of this sentence is the speaker, "I."

Hope this helps!